# Buscador de documentos usando MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, regex, mongodb, express

tengo una estrucutra CRUD de un aplicacion de inventarios, tengo una coleccion donde estan todos los productos y estoy tratando de implementar un buscador con un input de EJS, la cuestion es que no logro hacer ninguna busqueda del todo, estoy muy frutrado ayuda plissss.

Aqui esta el codigo de EJS del formulario:

```
<form class="form-inline justify-content-center" action="/find" method="GET">
<button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" value="search">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

Aqui esta la funcion para buscar

```
router.get('/find', async (req,res) => {
 const busqueda = await Productos.find({Descr: "7750912148467"});

 res.render('search', {
    busqueda
 });
```

});

Lo que no sé, es como paso el texto del input para que la función lo procese y busque los documentos que coincidan :8
He revisado acerca del metodo $regex pero no se como implementarlo, apreciaria mucho un poco de ayuda. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Debes conectar tu front (HTML) con tu Back (NodeJS), por eso no te llega al método `find`. Podrías hacerlo con [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

Yo pasaría la información del input por metodo POST, luego desde el back recibiría esa petición.
Dentro de la función del router.post, hago lo siguiente:

```
router.post('/productos/filtrado', async (req, res) => {
    const { filterBrand, filterType } = req.body;
    const typeProducts = await TypeProduct.find().sort({prefix: 'asc'});
    const brands = await Brand.find().sort({brand: 'asc'});

    const products = await Product.find();
    var filteredProducts = [];
    if(filterBrand === '' && filterType === "" ){
        res.redirect('/productos');
    }
    else{
    for await (product of products){
        if(filterBrand == product.brand && filterType == product.productType){
            filteredProducts.push({ product });
        }
    }
    res.render('products/all-products-filter', { filteredProducts, typeProducts, brands });
    }
});
```

En este caso está hecho para que desde el front dos select me envíen sus valores, pero se debería hacer lo mismo con un input de tipo texto (tené cuidado porque la busqueda la hace sindo sensible a minusculas y mayusculas).
La variable products almacena todos los productos guardados y luego la itero en el for of, buscando valores iguales, si el valor es igual, almaceno en un arreglo aparte al producto que coincide, y así con todos.
Luego lo envío a la vista y lo muestro.
Saludos!